# How to access 5xxxx Modbus address

Tags: c#, modbus

I am trying to access addresses such as 50526 on a Socomec Diris A40 using nmodbus. Unlike other examples I have seen which start with 3 or 4, these addresses all start with a 5. 50544, 50550, 50556 are but a few more im intersted in.

As far as I understand it at the moment, the first number represents the Modbus function and does not actually refer to the real address, i.e. 30000 addresses use function 04, 40000 addresses function 03 (?). I have seen the first digit omitted and the rest used as the address. If I try this with my 50000 addresses I get some success, but not with all values and the results dont seem correct. MODPOLL returns the same results as my code.

I could really use some help! If anyone can advise me on how to access these 5xxxx registers, I would be extremely grateful.

Method code:

```
    public static void ModbusSerialRtuMasterReadRegisters()
    {
        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1"))
        {
            // configure serial port

            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            try
            {
                port.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("port " + port.PortName + " open: " + port.IsOpen + "\n");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to open port: " + ex);
            }

            // create modbus master
            IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);

            byte slaveId = 1;
            ushort startAddress = 1;
            ushort numRegisters = 5;
            ushort[] registers = new ushort[numRegisters];;

            // read registers
            try
            {
                registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);
                for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("Register {0}={1}", startAddress + i, registers[i]);
            }
            catch (Modbus.SlaveException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find register... \n \n" + se);
            }

            try
            {
                port.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("\nport " + port.PortName + " open: " + port.IsOpen + "\n");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to close port: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to subtract 40001 or 40000 from 5xxxx address (addresses start with 1 or 0).

Comment: I have seen this suggested alright, but unfortunately it does not work for me. Having emailed the manfacturer, apparently they use 9xxxx addressing, i.e. 4 + 5, which would be base 4xxxx + 5xxxx im guessing, still waiting for clarification on that, but still no luck - the address 9xxxx also does not work (tested in Modbus Tester).

Comment: Their explanation here: "The thing is that our meter is using a NON STANDARD address mapping in this meter. 

Typically the address range for the data types are Modbus 41001 to 41099 – but our meter addresses have been mapped to up in the 9xxxx range (4+5).

 

One of our customers is working with the Kepware OPC/Modbus driver for his SCADA system interface. 

They had succeed to read and write 9xxxx addresses

My self, I use modbus tester through IP for some tests, and it works as well"

Comment: Ask them for a hexadecimal dump of single MODBUS request on any tag with known address. Then, since every byte in MODBUS message can be decoded, you can reverse engineer and find out the real "magic" address you need. The same can be achieved if they give you sniffed dump of some communication log with a working device, if addresses you are after are in it.

Comment: I have just looked at Kepware OPC server 4.xx help, and there are no 9xxxx addresses mentioned at all. It must be some pseudo address range mapped to base one since there are only 16 bits for an address, therefore maximum is 65535. Try functions 3 and 4 on addresses 1000/1001 and up, or addresses 11000/11001 and up.

Comment: So it seems even though I was told a number of times that the meter was a new model, it was in fact a pre-2009 model, something I found out after visiting the services department. This means I had been attempting to use the wrong address specification all along. As far as I can tell, addresses for the new post-2009 model work as descibed above, the addresses appearing as 9xxxx after entering 5xxxx (i.e. 4xxxx + 5xxxx). The older addresses however, are simple 4xxxx addresses - listed without the 4 prefix, '778' for example. I had tried using these also, but discovered you MUST read in 2...

Comment: ...at a time. If proper alignment isnt respected then the address will give an exception and appear to be invalid. The addresses are also JBUS, so possibly +/- 1 to get the target address.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry about having been asking technically the wrong question :P but this may help others and I think your answer and comments contain much relevant and helpful information, so I will accept that :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Registers with 5xxxx address are holding registers. (40001 to 5xxxx range)
So to find Modbus register address you should subtract its address from 40001.
for example 50512 - 40001=10511 (290F H)

good luck